# React Native Errors - VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps, react-google-places-autocomplete

I'm working on a react-native app and I have to put `GooglePlacesAutocomplete` in a Scrollview.This is the following code.

```
<ScrollView style={{flex: 1}>
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      minLength={2}
      nearbyPlacesAPI={'GooglePlacesSearch'}
      debounce={400}
      placeholder="Origin Address"
      query={{
        key: GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
        language: 'en',
      }}
      onFail={error => console.log(error)}
      enablePoweredByContainer={false}
      onPress={(data, details = null) => {
        console.log(details.geometry.location);
      }}
      fetchDetails={true}
      returnkeyType={'search'}
    />
  </ScrollView>
```

`Errors`: VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation because it can break windowing and other functionality - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
<ScrollView
    horizontal={true}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
 >
    <FlatList
        horizontal={true}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        scrollEnabled={false} 
        // .....
    />
</ScrollView>
```

This worked for me.Setting **scrollEnabled** to false on the flatlist removed the warning

Answer (score 1):

this error when you add vertival flatList inside ScrolView so try one of this :

1. change flat list to horizental
2. disable flat list scrolling , (from [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-places-autocomplete) disableScroll={false}).
3. use flat list it outside ScrollView ,  like in modal.

acording to react-native-google-places-autocomplete [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-places-autocomplete)
ther is section says:

Use Inside a  or 
If you need to include this component inside a ScrolView or FlatList, remember to apply the keyboardShouldPersistTaps attribute to all ancestors ScrollView or FlatList (see [this](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete/issues/486#issuecomment-665602257) issue comment).

Comment: I added `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}` in my `ScrollView` but still has this error

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
 style={{flex: 1}
 nestedScrollEnabled={true} // <---- 1.
>
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
  minLength={2}
  nearbyPlacesAPI={'GooglePlacesSearch'}
  debounce={400}
  placeholder="Origin Address"
  query={{
    key: GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
    language: 'en',
  }}
  onFail={error => console.log(error)}
  enablePoweredByContainer={false}
  onPress={(data, details = null) => {
    console.log(details.geometry.location);
  }}
  fetchDetails={true}
  returnkeyType={'search'}
  disableScroll={true} // <--- 2. this works
/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this was a difficult one. I was able to fix this by adding the `horizontal` and `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` props. This may cause an issue, with the list of addresses not showing up because of the set styling. You may need to add some styling to the `<Scrollview/>` using `contentContainerStyle.` This pseudo-code worked for me.

```
 <ScrollView
  horizontal={true}
  contentContainerStyle={{
   flexDirection: 'column',
   justifyContent: 'space-around',
   width: '100%',
  }}
  keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}>
   <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
     disableScroll={false}
   />
 </ScrollView>
```